# missing field value in cakephp 1.3 post array due to auto generation of dynamic form fields using JS

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I cannot receive all the form fields in my post array. This occurs due to auto - generation of form fields using JS. how can i overcome this? I am not using security component.

Is there a limit in using dynamic form fields? I can receive everything when my no. of fields is less but i cannot receive when it's too big. if so how can i increase the limit of usage?

If i use security component then my page ends up with 404-not found.

I can receive all the auto generated form fields but cannot receive some other fields which is not dynamic, it's created using form helper and these fields are below the auto generated fields.

using cake php 1.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the new settings in php.ini called

[`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

Increase the value of that setting and restart your web server and you should be fine.

Also make sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file (in case you do not notice any improvement)